# How does my textbook solve this summation equation for the answer?

Tags: algorithms, summation, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Summations have always been my weakness in mathematics, and it's showing here as I'm very confused how my textbook, *Introduction to Algorithms*, goes from basically the second half of the following picture, to saying it's O($n^2$). I included the top half in case more information was helpful.

[image]

Can anyone explain to me (as clearly as possible, I really am poor at summations) how to get to the bottom of that equation from the summation? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the step from the summation to the fraction.

The sum $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac 3 {16}\right)^i$$ is a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) with $r=\frac 3{16}$ and $a=1$. The sum of a geometric series is $$\sum=\frac a {1-r}$$so the sum of this series is $\frac 1 {1-\frac 3{16}}$.

As for the other steps:

- The step from (1) to (2) is true because all terms of the summation will be positive, so the sum of $n$ terms is always less than the sum of $\infty$ terms.
- The step from (2) to (3) is outlined above.
- The step from (3) to (4) is a simple evaluation of the fractional quantity.
- The step from (4) to (5) is true because $\frac {16}{13}c$ is a constant, and $O$-notation allows you to remove constants. Also, $n^{{\log_4}{3}} < n^2$ so we discard the smaller quantity.

Answer (score 1):

In the summation $$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_4n-1}\left(\frac3{16}\right)^icn^2$$ the factor $cn^2$ is a constant with respect to $i$, the index of summation, so we can pull it out:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_4n-1}\left(\frac3{16}\right)^icn^2=cn^2\sum_{i=0}^{\log_4n-1}\left(\frac3{16}\right)^i\;.$$

Now extend that last summation: the terms involved are all positive, so

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_4n-1}\left(\frac3{16}\right)^i<\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac3{16}\right)^i\;.$$

That last summation is a geometric series with ratio $\frac3{16}$, and since the absolute value of this ratio is less than $1$, we can apply the standard summation formula:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac3{16}\right)^i=\frac1{1-\frac3{16}}=\frac{16}{13}\;.$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_4n-1}\left(\frac3{16}\right)^icn^2<\frac{16}{13}cn^2\;.\tag{1}$$

Since $\frac{16}{13}c$ is constant, the righthand side of $(1)$ is $O(n^2)$, and since the exponent $\log_43$ is less than $2$, the $\Theta(n^{\log_43})$ term is also $O(n^2)$, making the whole thing $O(n^2)$.